# Export Sharepoint list to files and folders?

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-foundation, export

Does anyone know of a way of mass exporting files and folders that are stored in document libraries inside Sharepoint lists?

I've got this old Sharepoint site after a bankrupsy that we don't need anymore. But we do need a lot of the files that are stored inside Sharepoint.

So I was wondering if there's a tool of some sort that allows me to mass export these files to files and folders on a file share for example? Does Microsoft keep any tool like that? Can I use PowerShell for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this freeware tools as far as I know for exporting lists and other things off sharepoint

[spdeployment tool](http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/)

Comment: That seemed promising. Until it got exported to a cmp file. And in order to get the files out it seems I need a manifest.xml file as well. I just want the files out as files and folders. Not databases or anything like that. I did however find something called SPIEfolder that seems to do the trick. It's a command line tool though.

Comment: there are several ways of doing that but it depends on what you want, you used export word in your question so I thought you might want to export them only